# Outlook Anti-Spam plugin that allows deleting some and moving others to a SPAM folder

Tags: outlook, spam

I'm looking for a SPAM filtering solution, as a plugin to my Outlook, that allows me to specify that some emails containing phrases that I know **always** indicate SPAM should be deleted, but the rest should go to a SPAM or Junk Mail folder so I can review them for false positives. I could do the first part with Outlook's Rules, but the problem is that any anti-SPAM software I've used (including Microsoft's own Junk Mail filtering) always operates first, before the rules. Does anyone know of good software, free or otherwise, that would satisfy these requirements?

P.S. Please don't tell me to use something other than Outlook - its COM API is extremely useful to me, because I tie it in to my home-grown client database software for processing things like software registrations, payment notifications from email and license key requests for the software I sell.

Answer (score 1):

I actually found something after quite a bit of further searching, that seems to be working fairly well, and allows you to specify that its actions occur either before or after the Outlook Rules, which is just what I needed.

It is Spam Reader, from [www.spam-reader.com](http://www.spam-reader.com). It's commercial, but quite inexpensive. It's based on a bayseyian (sp?) approach.